# Show/Hide additional divs with link.

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Am using `mvc razor and jquery` and building UI dynamically based on DB Records.

In the section of the page am having lot of common information in a Separate `<div>` as mentioned below

```
<div id="Test"> </div>
<div id="Test"> </div>
<div id="Test"> </div>
<div id="Test"> </div>
..
..
<div id="Test"> </div>
```

and the content is dynamic. So what i was trying to achieve a Toggling design for the user

to show only 2 or 3 bottom `<div>` at a time and hide the other  and have **View more/View Less.**

And if user shows view more i will show everything and if they click View less i ll show 2-3 `<div>`

I tried to implement by getting the length of `<div>` and making `display:none;` but i was not 100% successful in what i want , so thought i ll get some fresh ideas here.

How do i achieve this in JQUERY  by keeping View more / Less as a Hyperlink ?
Thanks,

Comment: I updated the title of the question to reflect what I thought was more appropriate. If you disagree, feel free to revert the change! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [':eq()' selector in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

`:eq()` allows you to select items based on their index in the matched set. So `:eq(0)` is the first element and `:eq(3)` is the 4th.

[This is an example on fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ySjMM/1/)

And here is the code from the example:

```
// If the div isn't the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd in the set of matched divs, hide it
$('div:not(:eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2))').hide();

$(function () {
    $('#view-more-less').click(function () {
        $('div:not(:eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2))').toggle();
    })
});
```

Another approach is to wrap all divs except the first 3 in another container and hide that container with javascript. [Here's a fiddle for that approach.](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm97w/)

```
$('#view-more-less').click( function() {
    $('div.more-container').toggle();
});
```

On a side note, element id's must be unique. So you shouldn't use `id="test"` for all divs. Consider making test a class instead.